# Node js readable streams events differences

Tags: node.js, fs

I see many examples online using either 'data', 'open' and 'readable'. All seem to accomplish the same goal of streaming the input data / chunking input data. Why the variation and what's the exact differences between each event and when to use which for reading data?

Simple code examples:

```
 readStream.on('open', function () {
    // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
    readStream.pipe(res);
  });


readerStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
   data += chunk;
});
```

Comment: None of them do the same job. `open` tells you the file has been opened (This is not an event from `stream.Readable`, but from `fs.ReadStream` instead), `readable` tells you there are some new data from the stream, only `data` gives you the actual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

From node.js documentation:

Event `data`:
The `data` event is emitted whenever the stream is relinquishing ownership of a chunk of data to a consumer. This may occur whenever the stream is switched in flowing mode by calling readable.pipe(), readable.resume(), or by attaching a listener callback to the `data` event. The 'data' event will also be emitted whenever the readable.read() method is called and a chunk of data is available to be returned.

Attaching a `data` event listener to a stream that has not been explicitly paused will switch the stream into flowing mode. Data will then be passed as soon as it is available.

Find more about: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable